# Spring starter plugin issue in Eclipse Neon.2 : Unable to add Gradle Buildship

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I have installed Eclipse Neon.2 Release (4.6.2).

Also installed spring tools 3.8.3; when I am trying to create spring boot project using spring starter; I am not able to add Gradle Build ship type even I have installed it(Buildship: Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle 2.0.0.v20170111-1029).

I am getting following error :

 **Can not import using Gradle (Buildship) because Buildship Gradle Tooling is not installed. You can install it from Eclipse Marketplace.**

Comment: did you manage to create spring boot project using buildship?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the latest version of buildship [2.0](http://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/e46/releases/2.x/2.0.0.v20170111-1029) is not yet compatible with STS 3.8.3.

I uninstalled the 2.0 from marketplace, use this older version [1.0.21](http://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/e46/releases/1.0/1.0.21.v20161010-1640) and I was able create a spring boot project.